# How to delete test payments in shopify using Api?

Tags: shopify, recurring-billing

I have created an app and setup billing API. During testing I have created test payments and now I want to delete that payments. During deletion, I am getting this error

> Unprocessable Entity.

I am using bellow API to delete test payments "https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/recurringapplicationcharge#destroy". Please let me know how to delete test payments.

Thanks

Comment: Would you be able to post the code you used?

Comment: I have created an object of shopify and used that object to make Delete request.

$sc->call('DELETE','/admin/recurring_application_charges/12345678.json');

where 12345678 is the id of the charge request

Comment: Please reply @josh

Answer (score 1):

The API does not provide a way to delete recurring app charges. You can [cancel a charge](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/recurringapplicationcharge#destroy), but only if the status of the charge is `active`.

Comment: one more help please

Comment: I have created an shopify App and setting up recurring billing using Api. But now, I am confused about one thing i.e when to create charge and send confirmation url to customer so that he can accept/decline 1) On installing app 2) After 20 days as I also have 20 days trial facility  mentioned in the app. I have checked by installing other paid app and they not ask for accepting payment during installation (example app also having 7 days trial). Please let me know the best approach. Thanks

Comment: i am waiting for your reply... please do reply

Comment: Approach (1) is most common, but you could manage the trial on your own and create the charge at the end of the trial if you want to.

Comment: ok but as I also set trail of 20 days in the app setting and after managing trial on my own..will it effect the app approval when submitted for beta testing?

Comment: I don't see that being a problem for the app approval, so long as you use Shopify's billing system to create the charge whenever you are creating it.

Comment: ,so after installing app i will save that entey in DB and after trail ends i will crate charge using billing Api's....right?